# Why nginx works with error 301 HTTP1.1/Moved permanently?

Tags: nginx, url, webserver

I'm trying to configure Location directive on my nginx web-server (Ubuntu).

I can have access to:
http://127.0.0.1/app1/
BUT when I'm trying to get access whitout slash in the end like:
http://127.0.0.1/app1
I get an error **301 HTTP1.1/Moved permanently**

**I have following nginx config:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Looks like everything is OK.

**And following default.conf:**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /app1/ {
                root /var/www/html/;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /app1/index.html;
        }
}
```

**Curl output**
http://127.0.0.1/app1/

```
root@ubuntu-test:/etc/nginx/sites-available# curl 127.0.0.1/app1/ -Iv
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /app1/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2020 09:14:12 GMT
Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2020 09:14:12 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 5
Content-Length: 5
< Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Feb 2020 10:49:53 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Feb 2020 10:49:53 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5e4bc151-5"
ETag: "5e4bc151-5"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

http://127.0.0.1/app1

```
root@ubuntu-test:/etc/nginx/sites-available# curl 127.0.0.1/app1 -Iv
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /app1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2020 09:19:31 GMT
Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2020 09:19:31 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 194
Content-Length: 194
< Location: http://127.0.0.1/app1/
Location: http://127.0.0.1/app1/
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx selects the `location /` block to process the URI `/app1` as no other locations are a better match. See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

The `$uri/` term of the `try_files` statement informs Nginx to append a `/` to any URI that matches a directory. The directory `/var/www/html/app1` matches this requirement, so a 301 redirection is generated to append a `/` to the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

In addition, the default behaviour for a URI which ends with a `/` and points to a directory is to search that directory for a file that matches the `index` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

It is possible to deviate from this default behaviour, but you will need to make a number of changes to your configuration. The `location /app1/` needs to lose the trailing `/` if you want it to match `/app1`. Your `try_files` directives need to lose the `$uri/` term, if you want to avoid the 301 redirect. You will also lose default `index` processing, so the `index` directive will be useless.

Comment: I tried to delete ```try_files``` directive, also I've deleted trailing slash from ```/app1 ``` location. But it still doesn't work. http:127.0.0.1/app1 response is 301 error.

Comment: If you delete the `try_files` directive, Nginx will revert to default behaviour, which is to generate a 301 redirection. You need to keep the `try_files` directive and only remove the `$uri/` term.